# Making /media/mightyalex200/Data ( NTFS HDD) a RWX

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive, ntfs

I need to make `/media/mightyalex200/Data` accessible for me (or everybody) as RWX.

The only problem is that the Data HDD is a `NTFS` drive and I have no idea how to use `ntfs-3g`.

I'm also new to Ubuntu so please give me simple answers. (I'm doing this because on the drive there is a steam folder that needs to have execute permissions.)